# Pop up div from link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two links at the top of the page.. When I click on the link I would like it to open a popup box (that i am able to close) with the given information.  Right now if I click the link it will take me to that part on the page, but I lose the ability to click on the second link, unless i scroll all the way back to the top of the page.

Here is what i have as of now:
( I entered the dots to represent that there is code inbetween the popup functions; basically the same div boxes over and over again with just different channel numbers on each one)

```
<p style="font-size:16px"> Changed channels: <a href="#001" data-rel="popup">031</a>
```

(*I erased this second link to avoid confusion*)

```
.
.
.
.
.
.

<div id="LayoutDiv3">
  <div data-role="popup" id="001">
<div id="Leftbox">001</div>
    <div id="chan_logo" style="max-width: 30%"><img src="imgs/chan_logo_01.png" alt="hello"></div>
    <div id="chan_title">

<br>
.
.
.
</div>
(please assume the number of div's are all accounted for)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this (please consider asigning a css class instead):

```
<script>
  function openPopup() {
    popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.style.display = "block";
  }

  function closePopup() {
    popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.style.display = "none";
  }      
</script>

<style>
  #myPopup {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:50px;
    right:50%;
    background-color: blue;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
  }

  #myExit {
    position: absolute;
    right:0px;
    text-align: right;
    color:white;
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>

<a href="#" onclick="openPopup(); return false;">Open Popup</a>
<div id="myPopup">
  <a href="#" id="myExit" onclick="closePopup();return false">x</a>
  Hello There

</div>
```

Other solution:

```
<html>
  <body>


    <script>
      function openPopup(mydiv) {
        popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
        popup.style.display = "block";
        myPopupContent = document.getElementById("myPopupContent");
        myPopupContent.textContent = document.getElementById(mydiv).textContent;
      }

      function closePopup() {
        popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
        popup.style.display = "none";
      }      
    </script>

    <style>
      #myPopup {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top:50px;
        right:50%;
        background-color: blue;
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
      }

      #myExit {
        position: absolute;
        right:0px;
        text-align: right;
        color:white;
        background-color: red;
      }
    </style>

    <div id="myPopup">
      <a href="#" id="myExit" onclick="closePopup();return false">x</a>
      <div id="myPopupContent"></div>
    </div>


    <a href="#" id="chan001" onclick="openPopup('chan001'); return false;">Foo</a>
    <a href="#" id="chan002" onclick="openPopup('chan002'); return false;">Fii</a>
    <a href="#" id="chan003" onclick="openPopup('chan003'); return false;">Faa</a>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Davidos, thanks alot.  your solution worked.  I hate to be greedy but i have no way of closing the popup window.  is the closing of the window in the code you supplied ? (maybe i have an error somewhere) or do i need an additional command to have an "x" in the upper right hand corner ?

Comment: Thanks... my only issue now is that my whole div dissappears when i place the <div id = "myPopup"> above the div in question.  it pops up the window when i press the link , but if i just choose to scroll down the web page the div is no longer visible (no space or anything, it just moves the next "div" up).  ive tried switching div places... and even tried making the "popup call" id the same name as the div (LayoutDiv3) .. no luck .. sorry to bug you .. but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the #myPopup has the css style `display: none;` this means that everything inside it will be invisible. 
I think i dont understand exactly what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I have a list of 200 channels.... each channel is in its own div .. they alternate between "LayoutDiv1" and "LayoutDiv2"... when there is a channel change i highlight the div red with "LayoutDiv3".. at the top of the page i keep a list of the channels changed with a link behind the channel # that takes you to that spot on the webpage.  i'd like to just be able to click on the channel links and have a popup window appear so i dont have to scroll down the webpage(or have the link take me there) i dont wont the original div to disappear..i just want the popup "additionally" maybe too complcated?

Comment: ive tried just maybe putting the header that contains the channel links at a fixed position at the top of the page .. but when i scroll down the div's are partially blocked by the header. (kinda hiding behind the fixed header). so i thought pop ups would be better.  sorry about the confusion ..

Comment: create a css class. Style it as a popup, then assign the class to your div (then it will be displayed as a popup) then remove the css class on a press of the x.    OR   make a div popup, then use javascript to show it and fill in the values that you want see there, then on a click on the x, just hide it again

Comment: please see my edit again. Hope this will get you the idea!

Answer (score 1):

I hope you will get your problems solutions in below code.

```
<a href="#" onclick="GetPopUp(); return false;" > Click Here </a>
```

You should write code for create pop up design in html code. That is always `display:none`.

Now write JavaScript code in for pop up window.

```
function GetPopUp(){
 $('#divid').dialog(function(){
   title : 'new pop up',
   height : 500,
   width : 1000,
   model : true
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So where exactly is the code for opening the popup?

You have to create a Javascript function which creates a new "window" class and opens it.

after that you have to add the **onClick=">nameOfJSFunction<"** attribute to  element.

For example:

```
<a href="#" onClick="openPopup()">Open a new Popup</a>
```

and then the JS part:

```
<script>
function openPopup()
{
    newPOPUP = window.open('>LINKtoPOPUPfile<', '>TITLE<', '>OPTIONS<');
    newPOPUP.focus();
}
</script>
```

The file which the popup code is opening should contain the code/elements you want to see inside of the popup.

Comment: These kind of popups will be blocked by most browsers.

Comment: Yes but this is the natural popUp. Anything else, like jquery dialogs is not a real popup with the benefits of a popup: unique connection, unique window, and so on.. the solution with jquery for example has to use already loaded code or load it dynamicaly with ajax request. the window.open dialog creates an own GET request. Since he was asking for POPUP I wanted to provide a solution for POPUPS, not jquery dialogs.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm trying to get everything under divlayout3 to act as a popup.  there are around 200 alternating div's on the webpage, and if i click on one of the channel numbers on top of the page I would like  it bring up that particular channel number div.  Ex:  If I click on channel 001 I want it to pop up the whole div; the channel number, logo, etc.  All of the graphics and everything are contained inside of the div im trying to call.  so there is really no "link" to call .. if that makes sense ..

Comment: Then you cant use native popups like in My example.  Check the example of davidos krausos. You have to "grab"  the div using its id either with native js or using jquery and display the HTML of it inside a jquery dialog.